# How to login into an website which is authenticated by google + API using python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

How to get logged into some website using python code
`i.e www.example.com/auth/gmail` which is taking advantage of google+ API for user logins. Now I would like to login with my credentials (Gmail or What?) by using python code. Please help me how to approach towards this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example by using the google-api-python-client
First of all you have to create your client secrets on the google developer console.

First time you execute the code you will have to authorize the script to use your gmail account, then you can save the credentials on a file as on the example, and use it for the future executions without requiring this authentication

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from apiclient import errors
from oauth2client import client
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def getCredentials(secrets, scope,filename):
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
            secrets,
            scope=scope,
            redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    webbrowser.open(auth_uri)
    auth_code = raw_input('Enter the auth code: ')
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
    saveJson(filename,credentials.to_json())


def saveJson(filename, object):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(object, f)

def openJson(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        object = json.load(f)
    return object

if __name__=='__main__':
    client_secrets = 'client_secrets.json' #client secrets to use the API
    credentials = 'auth_credentials.json'
    if(firstRun) #create a file with the auth credentials
        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gemail.send'
        getCredentials(secrets,scope,credentials)

    cre = client.Credentials.new_from_json(openJson(credentials))
    http_auth = cre.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    gmail = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
    #gmail.doSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

this is old(sandbox) and is done really fast so, you have to refactor the code

```
import re
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import datetime
import string
import get_mail_search
from sys import stdout

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
class Get_mail(object):
    """docstring for Get_mail"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Get_mail, self).__init__()
        c=1
        self.login(c)
        self.toast_msg()

        raw_input()
    def toast_msg(self, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        M = self.mailbox()
        stdout.write("\n{}\n".format(get_mail_search.search_help_info))
        serach_input = raw_input()
        rv, data = M.search(None, serach_input)
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "No messages found!"
        id_ls = data[0].split()
        rev_id_ls = [i for i in reversed(id_ls)]
        if rev_id_ls:
            for o in rev_id_ls:
                try:
                    msg_content = self.process_mailbox(M, o)
                    _date_ = msg_content[0]
                    _from_ = msg_content[1]
                    _to_   = msg_content[2]
                    _subject_ = msg_content[3]
                    _msg_   = msg_content[4]
                    stdout.write("$$$$$$$$$$$\nDate: {}\nFrom: {}\nTo: {}\nSubject: {}\nMSG: {}\n".format(_date_,_from_,_to_,_subject_,_msg_))
                except Exception, e:
                    pass
        else:
            stdout.write("No {} Mail Found!".format(serach_input))
            raw_input()
            self.toast_msg()

    def login(self, try_c, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        try:
            stdout.write("\nMail:\n")
            mail = raw_input()
            if mail:
                M.login(str(mail), getpass.getpass())
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            if try_c<=3:
                stdout.write("Versuch: {}/3\n".format(try_c))
                stdout.write("Die eingegebene E-Mail-Adresse und das Passwort stimmen nicht uberein. Nochmal versuchen")
                try_c+=1
                self.login(try_c)
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
    def mailbox(self, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        rv, mailboxes = M.list()
        if rv == 'OK':
            for menu in mailboxes:
                print('{}'.format(menu))
            rv, data = M.select("inbox")
            if rv == 'OK':
                return M
    def eval_decode(self, header, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        return email.Header.decode_header(header)[0]

    def process_mailbox(self, M, num, *args):
        """docstring for Get_mail"""
        rv, header = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
        header_msg = email.message_from_string(header[0][1])
        if header_msg.is_multipart():
            body=[payload.get_payload(decode=True) for payload in header_msg.get_payload()]
        else:
            body=payload.get_payload(decode=True)
        from_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['From'])
        subject_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['Subject'])
        date_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['Date'])
        to_decode = self.eval_decode(header_msg['To'])
        return (date_decode[0], from_decode[0], to_decode[0], subject_decode[0], str(body[0]))
def run():
    try:
        Get_mail()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        M.close()
        M.logout()
        sys.exit(1)
run()
```